# How to install tensorflow-gpu==1.11.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

My project needs tensorflow==1.11.0
But when I tried to install it, I got:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.11.0
Looking in indexes: http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.11.0 (from versions: 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0, 1.15.0rc0, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0rc3, 1.15.0, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0rc0, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.1.0rc0, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0rc2, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.2.0rc0, 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==1.11.0
```

Plus, I am using py3.7.

Answer (score 3):

Some python versions are incompatible with some versions of Tensorflow. If you very specifically need Tensorflow 1.11.0 then you can probably install it in a Python 3.6 environment.

If you very specifically need Python 3.7, you can probably install Tensorflow 1.13.1 or later.

Comment: ok! Thanks! but I am using cuda10, yet tf1.11.0 needs cuda 9. Is there any solution to fix this problem? Thanks again!